# Get reference to variable from FieldInfo

Tags: c#, mono

I am working on a project where a field name from XML is loaded and the field with that name is returned and added to the current object. The problem is that FieldInfo.GetValue seems to return the current value of the field, not a reference. Is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No unfortunately there is not.  The design of `FieldInfo.GetValue` is to provide the value and not a reference.  There is no other suitable method on `FieldInfo` to provide a reference either.

One reason why is that doing so would be simply unsafe.  Imagen the scenario where the object is a `struct` on the stack.  If a `FieldInfo` could provide a reference to a field of that `struct` then it would be supplying a reference to a piece of the stack which could go away at any moment.  Reading or writing that reference after the stack went away would be incorrect and a type safety violation.

Comment: That sucks. I want to be able to do that. There need to be some way.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it with an expression tree. This works for NativeAOT too!

```cs
private delegate ref int GetRefDelegate(MyClass obj);

private static ref int EchoRef(ref int x)
{
    return ref x;
}

private class
{
    public in MyField;
}

public static Main()
{
    var objParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Test), "obj");
    var echoRef = Expression.Lambda<GetRefDelegate>(
        Expression.Call(
            typeof(Program).GetMethod(nameof(EchoRef), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic),
            new Expression[]
            {
                Expression.Field(objParam, typeof(Test).GetField("MyField"))
            }
        ),
        false,
        new ParameterExpression[] { objParam }
    );

    var obj = new MyClass();
    ref int gotRef = ref echoRef.Compile()(obj);
}
```

For some reason, the expression tree compiler can understands that a field reference is needed with a method invocation with a reference parameter, but it cannot recognize the same when the return type is with a reference parameter. That's why you need to invoke the dummy `EchoRef` method.